# Why this code doesn't work in visual-studio 2017?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int sum = 0;
int count = 0;
double avg = sum / count;

for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 3 != 0) {
        sum += i;
        count++;
    }
    else {
        continue;
    }
}

cout << "sum : " << sum << endl;
cout << "avg : " << avg << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Why this code doesn't work?
Why this code doesn't work?
Why this code doesn't work?
Why this code doesn't work?

Comment: That automated check for too much code and too little other text is there for a reason. Trying to circumvent it will just get you downvotes. Please explain what you're trying to do, how you're trying to do it, and exactly how your code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = 0;
double avg = sum / count;
```

0 as a divisor

Answer (score 1):

Code in a function executes from top to bottom. Where you do `double avg = sum / count;` happens before you've computed the desired values of `sum` and `count`. Since `count` is 0 at that point you try to divide by zero, which is an error.

I've moved that line after the loop and it now appears to work correctly.

Note that both `sum` and `count` are `int` types so you get *integer division* and maybe not the answer you expect. To get a result with digits after the decimal point at least one of the values needs to be a floating-point type. That's why I used `static_cast` on `sum` to get a floating-point divide and result.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        if (i % 3 != 0) {
            sum += i;
            count++;
        }
    }

    double avg = static_cast<double>(sum) / count; // moved here and do floating-point division

    cout << "sum : " << sum << endl;
    cout << "avg : " << avg << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thx for your codes!!!

Comment: @ipsae You're welcome. Please also read the answer and don't just copy the code.